# Linux: Warn Python Script of Restart

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi which uses a USB wireless adapter and wicd-curses.  A Python script runs in the background which uses a WebSocket.  When I call `sudo reboot`, my Python script gets the signal to restart (with SIGTERM) about 20 seconds later.  (I don't know why the computer takes 20 seconds to restart anyway.  I don't remember it being this way before installing wicd-curses.)

By the time 20 seconds has passed, wicd-curses has already disconnected from the wireless network, meaning my Python script cannot properly close the WebSocket connection.  So the core of my question is this:  what Python commands are available to me to ensure that my script is notified of the system shutdown earlier than it is now?  Is there any sort of event for which I can listen?  Preferably, I want to be able to run the script on demand (`python myscript.py`) without the use of a daemon or service or whatever it might be called in the Linux world.  Thank you.

Comment: This question might be better suited for superuser rather than SO. [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: This depends almost completely on what init system you're using (e.g., OpenRC, Systemd, sysvinit, etc). The init system will have a mechanism for handling daemon dependencies, which can start up (and shut down) things in the proper order).

Comment: @jramirez, I see it more as a programming question than a system administration question.  But that's because I was thinking about solving the problem in code rather than by changing Linux settings.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy, I'll have to investigate that tomorrow.  I think I've tried to turn my Python script into a Linux service before, and it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: In response to those who put this question on hold, I would prefer to solve this problem through code rather than some Linux settings changes.  Please see my re-worded question.  This is not about "general computing hardware and software."  This is about Python programming.  Thank you.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, please see my comment above.  I'll be at-replying everyone who closed this question since I don't know how else to notify you all.

Comment: @ekhumoro, please see my comment above.  I'll be at-replying everyone who closed this question since I don't know how else to notify you all.

Comment: @mdml, please see my comment above.  I'll be at-replying everyone who closed this question since I don't know how else to notify you all.

Comment: @Duck, please see my comment above.  I'll be at-replying everyone who closed this question since I don't know how else to notify you all.

Comment: @DaveA, please see my comment above.  I'll be at-replying everyone who closed this question since I don't know how else to notify you all.